# redirect the user to a default ‘after logout’ page on shiro

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, shiro

Iam trying to do the task of redirecting the user to the login page automatically when he leaves the website for 30 min + (shiro consider him loged out ).

according to this page 
https://stormpath.com/blog/whats-new-apache-shiro-12/

i need to use  **logout.redirectUrl** in the ini

i tried but i was not successful on achieving this functionality
here is my ini

```
[main]

jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password from users where user_name = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role_name from users_roles where user_name = (select user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = ?)

ds = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
ds.serverName =localhost
ds.user = postgres
ds.password = 123456
ds.databaseName = example
jdbcRealm.dataSource= $ds


authc.loginUrl = /faces/login.xhtml
user.loginUrl = /faces/login.xhtml

logout.redirectUrl = /faces/login.xhtml

multipleroles = com.example.util.MultipleRolesAuthorizationFilter

[urls]
/faces/login.xhtml = authc
/faces/logout = logout
/faces/authorized/** = user, multipleroles["admin,guest"]
/faces/guest/** = user, multipleroles["admin,guest"]
/faces/admin/** = user, roles[admin]
```

Comment: Can you be more precise what the problem is. What isnt working? What is the logout doing now?

Comment: the logout is working perfectly . but what I am looking for is the following : when the user sty away from the computer , i expect shiro to log him out automatically and that is what its doing but when that happened it wont redirect him to the login page again , instead it will sty in the same page until he click on some link . i wanted to force the redirection to the login page

Comment: This sounds more like something you would do with some kind of javascript/push framework. When the user is logged out at the backend, nothing gets send to the browser, so it has no way to know it needs to redirect -until the user clicks something-. So this is more of a frontend/push/javascript issue than a shiro issue.

Comment: i like your suggestion, thanks ,although it still puzzled me that in the blog i mentioned , they were talking that the new versions of shiro support this task. thanks for your help

Comment: Greated it as an answer so this issue can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like something you would do with some kind of javascript/push framework. When the user is logged out at the backend, nothing gets send to the browser, so it has no way to know it needs to redirect -until the user clicks something-.

So this is more of a frontend/push/javascript issue than a shiro issue.

Comment: it wasnt totally what i was hoping as answer but thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your logout url really match your logout definition `/faces/logout`.

I am using spring integration, my config looks like:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />

        <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
                /login.jsp = anon
                /login.action = anon
                /logout = logout
                /** = authc
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logout" class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.LogoutFilter"> 
        <property name="redirectUrl" value="/login.jsp" /> 

    </bean>
```

`login.jsp` and `success.jsp` under the `webapp` folder, and in `success.jsp`,

logout link is: `<a href="logout">Logout</a>`